# Is Explorer.EXE (capitalized) a virus?

Tags: windows-xp

Recently I notice that in Task Manager, I have an Explorer.EXE (capitalized excactly as shown) process, not the usual explorer.exe

Is this normal? Is it a virus? I have uploaded the file to VirusTotal but it's not positive.

Comment: Where is that `Explorer.EXE` located? (Use [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) to find the actual path.)

Comment: If you suspect and infection [see this](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc/157533#157533)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, not necessarily.  Windows is case-insensitive, so EXPLORER.EXE and explorer.exe are consider to be the same entity; provided they reside at the same path location.  The correct location for Explorer is **C:\Windows\explorer.exe**.  If you have an Explorer.exe at a different location, then I would be a little more concerned.

You should get *Process Explorer*, a tool that gives the information you wish TaskManger was showing you, from the SysInternals site.  Microsoft bought SysInternals a few years ago because they, SysInternals, had a better grasp on the MS OSes than the MS developers did.

---

The reason that Explorer is shown in uppercase sometimes and lowercase others actually derives from the path that executed that instance of explorer.exe; for example, coming from a terminal services session, as is the case when using Remote Desktop to login, will show a capital explorer.exe (if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly depends on location. Any instances of Explorer.exe outside **%root%\Windows** should be carefully analised and threated as probable malware.

You may also use the website "VirusTotal" to check this possibility.

[VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/)

Also, how many instances of this process do you have?